# Path overriding controls beneath

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Related to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411012/clipping-to-a-path-in-wpf)

I have a set of check boxes in a grid, these check boxes are style to look like the parts of a shoe. (heel, edge, instep etc)

The user needs to be able to click the Edge (1 check box) and each of the other "Regions" seperately

Using the fabulous answer in the linked question I have got something that looks good.

However I am not able to select the edge. I can select each of the individual regions, but these are over the top of the edge meaning that they are selected before the mouse event can get to the edge path.

I have tried setting the Panel.ZIndex of the edge path and this enables me to select the edge, however this now stops me from selecting the individual regions.

**ZIndex = 0:**

[image]

**ZIndex = 99:**

[image]

Can someone point me to a solution?

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="200">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <PathGeometry x:Key="DynamicClipGeometry" Figures="{StaticResource ShoeEdgeFigures}">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <converters:SizeToScaleConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}" />
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Clip>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="DynamicClipGeometry" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <!--  The edge check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeEdgeRegion"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.RowSpan="5">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Path x:Name="MainPath"
                                          Data="{StaticResource ShoeEdgeGeometry}"
                                          Fill="Transparent"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                          Stretch="Fill" 
                                          Stroke="Black"
                                          StrokeThickness="-10" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <!--  The Toe check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeToeRegion" Grid.Row="0">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MainPath"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <!--  The Sole check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeSoleRegion"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="0,-1,0,0">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MainPath"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <!--  The Instep check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeInstepRegion"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Margin="0,-1,0,0">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MainPath"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <!--  The Lower heel check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeLowerHeelRegion"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Margin="0,-1,0,0">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MainPath"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <!--  The heel check box  -->
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShoeHeelRegion"
                  Grid.Row="4"
                  Margin="0,-1,0,0">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MainPath"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                               Stroke="Black"
                                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="MainPath" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with setting `Panel.ZIndex` is a good one.

The key to success here is the crucial difference between a `Transparent` brush and a `null` brush (i.e. no brush at all).

In terms of visual features they are the same - `Transparent` brush is lookless, so we don't see any difference. But in terms of mouse input it is solid, which means it takes part in hit-testing, whereas when there's no brush, there's nothing to hit-test.

To put it in simple words - `Transparent` brush is invisible to human eye, but is visible to the mouse.

So what you're after is a path with hit-test visible stroke and no fill (as opposed to transparent fill). To achieve that you should modify your path with `IsHitTestVisible="True"` and `Fill="{x:Null}"`. Also, you need to set the background of the `Border` in your template to `null`, or drop it altogether, because it wouldn't serve any purpose anyway.

Here's how your edge `CheckBox` template should look like:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ShoeEdgeRegion" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Path x:Name="MainPath"
                              Data="{StaticResource ShoeEdgeGeometry}" 
                              IsHitTestVisible="True"
                              Fill="{x:Null}"
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              Stroke="Black"
                              StrokeThickness="-10" />
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MainPath" 
                                        Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MainPath" 
                                        Property="Stroke"
                                        Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

You could also omit setting `Path.IsHitTestVisible` and `Path.Fill` properties since those are default values for these properties.

Comment: Thank you so much that was amazing :-)